# linker command failed with exit code 1 Xcode

Tags: xcode

I keep getting this error code when attempting to build.

```
ld: entry point (_main) undefined. for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I know this probably isnt enough info so please tell me what else i need to show you. Please help I'm totally lost.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't have a main method

Comment: @aaronman wow that was a failure on my part... thanks solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

I got the point just add the main.m and AppDelegate.m in to build phase. It solved my problem